# Using python groupby or defaultdict effectively?

Tags: python-2.7, group-by, defaultdict

I have a csv with name, role, years of experience. I want to create a list of tuples that aggregates `(name, role1, total_exp_inthisRole)` for all the employess. 
so far i am able to use defaultdict to do the below

```
 import csv, urllib2
from collections import defaultdict 

response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
cr = csv.reader(response)
parsed = ((row[0],row[1],int(row[2])) for row in cr)    
employees =[]
for item in parsed:
    employees.append(tuple(item))
employeeExp = defaultdict(int)
for x,y,z in employees: # variable unpacking
    employeeExp[x] += z    
employeeExp.items()
```

output: `[('Ken', 15), ('Buckky', 5), ('Tina', 10)]`

but how do i use the second column also to achieve the result i want. Shall i try to solve by `groupby` multiple keys or simpler way is possible? Thanks all in advance.

Comment: Can you give an example of the result you want? I mean how you want to aggregate the columns?

Comment: Yes!
[('Ken', 'engineer', 5),('ken, 'sr. engineer', 6),...] or [('Ken', ('engineer', 5),('sr. engineer', 6)), ...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply pass a tuple of name and role to your `defaultdict`, instead of only one item:

```
for x,y,z in employees:
    employeeExp[(x, y)] += z
```

For your second expected output (`[('Ken', ('engineer', 5),('sr. engineer', 6)), ...]`)

You need to aggregate the result of aforementioned snippet one more time, but this time you need to use a `defaultdict` with a list:

```
d = defaultdict(list)

for (name, rol), total_exp_inthisRole in employeeExp.items():
    d[name].append(rol, total_exp_inthisRole)
```

Comment: Thanks! and what to do to achieve output like  [('Ken', ('engineer', 5),('sr. engineer', 6)), ...] ..so that later i can use the name as key of a dict assuming names are unique or replacing names with IDs.

Comment: i think .append((rol, total_exp_inthisRole)) one more '()' required. but yes it gives required form. thanks! :)