# Python: Iterating through a list of dictionaries to retrieve a value and store in another list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists of dictionaries.
Both of them are derived from CSV files with about 100k rows.
A sample of the first list containing reference data is as follows.

```py
[{'ID': 'A1', 'app3 vers': '8'}, 
 {'ID': 'A2', 'app3 vers': ''}]
```

My base data looks like this:

```py
[{'ID': 'A1', 'app1 vers': '4', 'app2 vers': '3'}, 
 {'ID': 'A2', 'app1 vers': '2', 'app2 vers': '4'}]
```

What I want to do is the following.
Search the reference data with for the ID. If the app version is present, append it to the relevant data. If it is not, append `'not present'` so my results would look like this:

```py
[{'ID': 'A1', 'app1 vers': '4' , 
   'app2 vers': '3', 'app3 vers': '8'}, 
 {'ID': 'A2', 'app1 vers': '2', 
   'app2 vers': '4', 'app3 vers': 'not present'}]
```

I have created some code which works fine with test data, however when I use it against live data it is taking around 35 mins to run.
I am looking for a way to improve this performance.

The code I have created is:

```py
# append new app3 vers column with a default of not present
base_dict['app3 vers'] = 'Not Present'

# loop through the list of base dictionaries
for individual_dict_items in list_of_base_dicts: 
   currentid = base_dict['ID']  # Get ID

   # loop through the reference list of dictionaries matching the id
   for ref_dicts in reference_data_list:
      if currentid in ref_dicts.values():
         # if found set the app3 vers column to value
         base_dict['app3 vers'] = ref_dicts['app3 vers']
```

This code returns what I expect but is very slow handling larger data sets

Comment: can you provide your code - it'll be easier to suggest something if one can see what you have, and the type of data it's operating on. Right now it sounds like you need to potentially use `defaultdict` to group items into a new dict. This answer may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37454764/using-python-groupby-or-defaultdict-effectively

Comment: Your reference and base data do not represent valid Python data structures

Comment: Hi I cannot provide the provide the actual source data for security reasons. The reference data is a list of dictionaries the list contains 69k dictionaries and each dictionary has 5 key/value items.

The base Data is another list of dictionaries.  The list contains 69k Dictionaries and each dictionary has 76 key/value items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is slow because you go over every value in your reference list for every value of your base list.

To improve performance, you can change the reference list from a list of dictionaries to a single dictionary, indexed on your IDs.
The following code performs this transformation for you using [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```py
base_dict = {d['ID']: d['app3 vers'] for d in refdata}
```

Now, you can remove the code that searches for the ID with a simple `base_dict[currentid]`, which will return the version you are looking for.

Note that this code assumes that the IDs in your reference data are unique.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is actually to join the 2 arrays (see database left-joins).

Your way of doing using nested loops is an intuitive but naive solution. This solution has a complexity of `O(n*m)` where.

A more efficient one is to create a dictionary ahead of the join. This takes some time, but it does not increase complexity the way nested loops do. Here is an example :

```py
ref_data = [
    {'ID': 'A1', 'app3 vers': '8'}, 
    {'ID': 'A2', 'app3 vers': ''}
]
base_data = [
    {'ID': 'A1', 'app1 vers': '4', 'app2 vers': '3'}, 
    {'ID': 'A2', 'app1 vers': '2', 'app2 vers': '4'}
]

# create a dictionary with the ref data to find elements with a O(1) complexity
# Complexity : O(n)
ref_data_dict = {}

for ref in ref_data:
    ref_data_dict[ref['ID']] = ref

# create a new list with left-joined data
# Complexity : O(m)
joined_data_list = []

for d in base_data:
    joined_element = copy.copy(d)
    element_id = d['ID']
    ref_element = ref_data_dict[element_id] # O(1)
    joined_element['app3 vers'] = ref_element['app3 vers'] or 'not present'
    
    joined_data_list.append(joined_element)
```

This code has a complexity of `O(n+m)`, which is way better. The code can be improved, as I tried to make it understandable and not perfectly suited.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect your code (which you've chosen not to share) is comprised of nested loops which may be making it slow.

You should rearrange your base data which you can do in a single pass.

Then you need a single pass over your reference data as follows:

```
refdata = [
    {"ID": "A1", "app3 vers": "8"},
    {"ID": "A2", "app3 vers": ""}
]
basedata = [
    {"ID": "A1", "app1 vers": "4", "app2 vers": "3"},
    {"ID": "A2", "app1 vers": "2", "app2 vers": "4"}
]

newbasedata = dict()

for d in basedata:
    for k, v in filter(lambda k: k[0] != "ID", d.items()):
        newbasedata.setdefault(d["ID"], []).append((k, v))

for d in refdata:
    if (vlist := newbasedata.get(d["ID"])) is not None:
        d.update(vlist)
    for k, v in d.items():
        if not v:
            d[k] = "not present"

print(refdata)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'ID': 'A1', 'app3 vers': '8', 'app1 vers': '4', 'app2 vers': '3'}, {'ID': 'A2', 'app3 vers': 'not present', 'app1 vers': '2', 'app2 vers': '4'}]
```